# Biopython in Jupyter Notebook? Windows 7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, biopython

I have already installed Python version 3.6 on windows and also Anaconda. I want to use Biopython package on my code in Jupyter Notebook. I also installed the biopython using the command:

```
conda install -c anaconda biopython=1.68
```

When I want to run my code below, it doesn't work. fasta is only a file containing sequences.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
handle = open("Q1.fasta")
record_iterator = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
seq1_20 = record_iterator.next()
seq2_20 = record_iterator.next()
seq3_20 = record_iterator.next()
seq1_100 = record_iterator.next()
seq2_100 = record_iterator.next()
handle.close()
print seq1_20
print seq2_20
print seq3_20
print seq1_100
print seq2_100
```

It should output those sequences, but it says:

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d5af48173555> in <module>()
  2 handle = open("Q1.fasta")
  3 record_iterator = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
----> 4 seq1_20 = record_iterator.next()
  5 seq2_20 = record_iterator.next()
  6 seq3_20 = record_iterator.next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Please, someone help me to get out of this!

Comment: Did you try googling the `AttributeError` python is throwing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your example code will work on Python 2 only.

Python 3 did away with the `.next()` method on iterator classes, you should use the builtin function `next(...)` instead (available in Python 2.6 onwards).

Try `next(record_iterator)` instead.